# Set jetty "document root" / project folder from terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, jetty, symlink

Say that I want to run jetty from the Ubuntu 13.04 terminal. Apparently jetty uses its /webapps folder to store my projects, but I have my projects in my Dropbox folder and I don't want to move them to /webapps.

I've tried to create a symbolic link to my Dropbox project directory (link is at `~/Apps/jetty/webapps/yc`, pointing to `~/Dropbox/YCalculator`), but visting `localhost:8080/yc/` after starting the server via `java -jar ~/Apps/jetty/start.jar` results in a 404 error, "HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing /yc/. Reason: Not Found".

- Is there any way to set my jetty project directory via the terminal?
  (For example, something like `java -jar start.jar
  jetty.home=~/Dropbox/YCalculator`? [Doesn't work.])
- Or, better yet, link to the folder with a symbolic link or something similar?
- Or, less-preferred, is there a configuration file I can change to set my preferred directory?

Also, my YCalculator folder has a /war and /src folder. I originally made the project in Eclipse with the Google App Engine plugin, but Eclipse is pretty slow on this laptop and I was hoping to be able to run *just* jetty from the terminal, instead of booting up Eclipse just to run the test server from there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I rather than going to `localhost:8080/yc/`, I had to go to `localhost:8080/YCalculator/war/`. Then index.html displayed correctly.